# MethodNotAllowedHttpException with POST method

Tags: php, laravel-5.4

I am very new with Laravel and facing some problem with it. I am trying to make a register page and facing MethodNotAllowedHttpException after I submitted the form. I have searched many of posts and still get nothing. Could someone help me to find out what should I do? Here is my code.

**web.php**

```
Route::get('/farm/register', 'AccountsController@create');
Route::post('/farm', 'AccountsController@store');
```

**AccountsController.php**

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    dd(request()->all());
}
```

**register.blade.php**

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ URL::route('/farm') }}" >
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work, but try this:

```
Route::post('/farm', 'AccountsController@store')->name('farm')

<form method="post" action="{{ route('farm') }}" >
{{ csrf_field() }}
```

This works for me.

Comment: This might be late, but Thank you :)